# Exporting displacement map

Tags: blender

can anyone help me with how to export the heightmap from blender, I export the Normal, Spec, and Color by just adding image texture and plugging it into BSDF shader, and export the model in obj. But the displacement texture do not export as other texture!

Comment: Hi and welcome :) If you're question is about how to do this via Python scripting in Blender and it's a programming question that could be answered here (in which case posting a code snippet of your attempt along with notes on what doesn't work and what's the expected behaviour will help a lot). If it's a question on how to use the Blender interface and it's not programming related a better place for the question is https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.